# Workflow Approval _ModerationStatus is always set to approved even though it says pending in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365

I have a standard publishing workflow and I am trying to get the `_ModerationStatus` from my documents so I can only show approved documents.  My problem is that no matter what state my document is (pending, approved etc.) the internal column `_ModerationStatus` is ALWAYS set to approved or 0.  In my UI view of my document library one of my documents will say pending, but I open up the client browser and look at the internal `_ModerationStatus` column and it's actually set to 0 or Approved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I had to go to the document library settings and then go to version settings and select Yes on content approval, otherwise no matter what the workflow says the internal `_ModerationStatus` will default to approved.